# Implementing OCPP methods

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I created a SOAP client and server on same .js file.

**index.js**

```
"use strict"
var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;
var express = require('express');
var Promise = require('promise');
var app = express();
var WSDL = soap.WSDL;


var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('centralsystemservice_1.5.wsdl','utf8');
var xmlCl = require('fs').readFileSync('chargingpointservice_1.5.wsdl','utf8');
var url = './chargingpointservice_1.5.wsdl';
function aa(args)
{
    console.log("<<<>>>",args.bb);
}


var path = "/dek";
var port = 9330;






soap.createClient(url, {}, (err, client) => {
  if(err)
    throw err;
  else 
  {
    client.setEndpoint('http://localhost:9330/Ocpp/ChargePointService/');
    client.ChargePointService.ChargePointServiceSoap12.Reset();
  }
});

app.post('/Ocpp/ChargePointService/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req);
})



app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port "+port);
  soap.listen(app, path, service, xml);
});
```

I can't write content of .wsdl files because of being too long. I have a question: How i can implenent functions like heartbeat or bootnotification? Are there any constraints on writing functions to communicate in OCPP protocol?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you use json instead of soap. Using json is much easier.

Example, in the case of BootNotification, a station boot and send to your Ocpp server:

```
 [2,
     "19223201",
     "BootNotification",
     {"chargePointVendor": "VendorX", "chargePointModel": "SingleSocketCharger"}
    ]
```

And your server answers with:

```
  [3,
     "19223201",
     {"status":"Accepted", "currentTime":"2013-02-01T20:53:32.486Z", "heartbeatInterval":300}
    ]
```

Literally that's it